# How to transform rows in Columns with Cube, Pivot or Rollup SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this information:

```
code    score    quality
123     2015      12
123     2016      16    
123     2017      14
```

I would like to show like that

```
  code    2015    2016  2017
    123    12      16    14
```

Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using conditional aggregation:

```
select code,
    max(case when score = 2015 then quality end) as [2015],
    max(case when score = 2016 then quality end) as [2016],
    max(case when score = 2017 then quality end) as [2017]
from your_table
group by code;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NLDM40896)

Or using `PIVOT`:

```
select *
from your_table
pivot (
    max(quality) for score in ([2015],[2016],[2017])
) p;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/IYAS52425)

Comment: EXCELENT!!! thank you very much! Is easy for you, but difficult to me now. Greatings.

Comment: is only difficult until you learn it. The sintaxis is there, if you have another question just ask. But that is the way to do it.